# How do you reset a shape to its original template with Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to orchard and this maybe very simple thing to do.

I have been using the Designer Tools module and created an Alternate shape. This set this new alternate shape as the Active Template. Is the a way to set the Active template to the original template?

Many thanks

Andy

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Delete your alternate file?

Comment: That worked, I knew it was something simple. If you add it as an answer, I'll make it the approved answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your alternate file and it will fall back on the default.